# Time of day used by Cortana makes no sense

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I like Cortana and use it quite a bit, but I'm seeing some goofy behavior on my 15063.250 work machine and possibly on my other Windows 10 devices.  If at say 2:10 pm I ask Cortana to set a reminder to call Bob at 2:30 it makes the appointment for 2:30 am tomorrow.  Is there any way to change the how Cortana handles times for reminders?

Comment: does your PC use a 24h time format? did you try to say 2:30 pm or 14.30 o'clock? Try changing the clock to 12h format.

Comment: Make sure Cortana knows what time zone you are in.  Make sure your system time zone is correct.

Comment: My clock is set to 12 hour.  I'm in the US and my time zone is correct UTC-5 Eastern Time US and Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Use **what time is it** in cortana to see if the current time on your System and the current time that Cortana tells you are different.

Check All the language setting in your Region and speech, and check the time zone setting.

Comment: What time is it doesn't seem to be hooked up in Cortana on my 15063.250 work machine.  It opens the alarms and clock.

Comment: `what time is it` is supported by 1703, but **15063.250**, over a year old.  You should immediately update to the current build by installing **KB4338827**

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue.  It does things at the correct time, it just assumes that if you are close to the time when you set the alarm, you want an alarm clock rather than a tea timer.

Comment: This is a work machine, so I'm not supposed to go updating it on my own.